# Key based intersection of two python dictionaries with priority

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets say I have 2 dictionaries, `a` and `b`:

```
a = {"a": 2, "b": 4}
b = {"a": 5, "b": 2, "c": 10}
```

I want to find the common keys in both dictionaries, and then take the value of those keys from `b` to create a new one. Example:

```
c = intersect_keys(a, b)
# c = {"a": 5, "b": 2}
```

As you can understand, the keys which were not present in the first array were not used in the newly generated one. How can I do this in a fast way using Python?

Moreover, because we are always picking the values from the second array, would it be better to just make `a` into a list and then iterate over it and then the values from `b`? Thanks for any answers.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I have tried doing it iteratively using a list instead, that is, the keys from the first array are stored in a list.

Comment: So give a [mcve] and explain the problem with that implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *dictionary comprehension*, in order to keep those keys in `b` that are also present in `a`:

```
{k:v for k,v in b.items() if k in a}
```

**Output**

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Is this faster than iterating a list of keys? That is, what if I stored the first dictionary as a list, like so: `a = ['a', 'b']`

Comment: @darkhorse have you tried profiling/timing it to find out? If that's your specific issue, what evidence do you have that the current implementation is a bottleneck?

Comment: As @jon suggests, you can try timing the approaches that are suggested as answers if performance is an issue. Also if you stored the keys in `a` as a list, then what? You still have to iterate over all keys in `b` which is what is being done here

Answer (score 1):

Try this?:

```
myKeys = set(a.keys()).intersection(b.keys())
c = {}
for key in myKeys:
    c[key] = b[key]
```

Comment: `{k:b[k] for k in set(a).intersection(b)}`

Comment: Tidier way of saying the same thing.
I didn't know dictionary comprehensions were a thing!

Comment: Well.. in a compiled language it would all turn to the same machine code. But, this is perhaps indeed more _pythonic_